# Configure WSO2 API Manager with a Loadbalancer with a domain name

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We want to run the WSO2 Api Manager application under the domain. Via https://domainname.com. The /carbon application is running and there is no problem. But /devportal and /publisher redirect to https://domainname.com:9443/authenticationendpoint and do not open. Afterwards, we saw that there are port information in the definitions in the identity.xml file. We also deleted the port information here. After restarting the WSO2 application, the changes we made were not saved. How can we fix this problem?

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps below.

1. Open `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` and add the following if you have not added it already. Once added restart the server.

```ini
[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443
[server]
hostname = "<loadbalancer_hostname>"
```

**Note:** Following steps are applicable only if you already started API Manager without the above `proxyPort` configuration and logged into any of the Portals. Then you have to change the already registered callback URLs. If you are starting with the fresh database with the above configurations following steps are not required.

2. Login into Carbon console. `https://<APIM_HOST>/carbon` and Navigate to `Service Providers -> List` then select the appropriate Service provider for a Portal. For Publisher the SP name would be `apim_publisher` Then click on `Edit`

[image]

3. Then Navigate to `Inbound Authentication Configuration -> OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration -> Edit`

[image]

4. Then locate the `Callback Url` Configuration and add the correct port and save it.

[image]

Note: You have to do this for all the Service Providers for each portal.

Also if you have a custom URL other than the one in `deployment.toml` you may need to generate the Callback URL based on the `X-Forward-for` header. You can read about this [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/#step-4-configure-the-dynamic-callback-origin).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ycr. The /publisher login screen was opened. But after entering the username and password information, we get the following error. How can we find out the reason for this error?

**Authentication Error!
Something went wrong during the authentication process. Please try signing in again.**

Comment: It redirects to the following url. 

**publisher/error-pages?code=500**

Comment: You should see a detailed error log in the `wso2carbon.log` file.